# MySQL - Find how many matches (Like 6/9 found) from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to figure out the number of matches between two tables.

Currently, I'm using this query, which results in the number of times a match is found.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM products WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inventory WHERE products.products_id = inventory.product_id) AND products.orders_id = 'xxx'
```

If there's 5 products and 3 of them can be found in the other table - It returns "3.

I need to be able to know how many rows there's total and how many of them are matched - Like 3 /5 is found. How would I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If products are unique in inventory, then the "normal" way is:

```
SELECT count(*) as total, count(i.product_id) as matches
FROM products p LEFT JOIN
     inventory i
     ON p.products_id = i.product_id
WHERE p.orders_id = 'xxx';
```

If `inventory` can have duplicates, then a simple method is:

```
SELECT count(distinct p.product_id) as total, count(i.product_id) as matches
FROM products p LEFT JOIN
     inventory i
     ON p.products_id = i.product_id
WHERE p.orders_id = 'xxx';
```

EDIT:

If you need to take quantity into account:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN i.qty > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: How would I modify this to make sure it only counts i.product_id if it has quantity >= 1?

Comment: @DennisA . . . `count(i.product_id)` only counts matches in the inventory.  So, it is essentially doing that.

Comment: Problem is, the quantity can be 0 in the table - Wouldn't that be a problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Lets try this

```
SELECT count(u.Product_id) as total, count(i.product_id) as matches
FROM products p 
LEFT  JOIN inventory i ON p.products_id = i.product_id
RIGHT JOIN inventory u ON p.products_id = u.product_id
WHERE p.orders_id = 'xxx';
```